# Google Adwords AdGroupCriterionService

Tags: c#, .net, google-ads-api

I am using Google Adwords Api "AdGroupCriterionService" service to retrieve all keywords and I have a related question.

How can I filter result (list of keywords) by "Clicks" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use predicates to filter the results.  The example here demonstrates how to create predicates:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-dotnet/source/browse/trunk/examples/adwords/csharp/v201109/BasicOperations/GetKeywords.cs#85

In your case you could use a predicate like Clicks GREATER_THAN 10, etc.